# Batch / Script for a scheduled Backup

Tags: batch-file, backup

Apologies on my poor knowledge of this subject, not very familiar with this but here goes.

I'm looking to create a script that will backup a file, and place it into a folder named with the current date, however i only require a backup if the file has been modified, as duplicates of the same file are not required.

I have a sample script i have found and modified it slightly to try and accommodate my needs,

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%HH%%Min%_%DD%%MM%%YYYY%"


echo ### Backing Up
ROBOCOPY C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Backup\testing.txt C:\Testbackup\\%datestamp% /fft /e /xo /xx /COPY:DAT

@pause
```

This works to a small extent.. it replicates the data inside regardless of changes due to the date stamp on the new directory this creates, i'm unsure how to get the script to analyse the "testing.txt" modification date instead of creating a new directory and replicating the file inside.

A push in the right direction would be a huge help,

As mentioned earlier, I am a "newbie" in coding, so be gentle :)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can live with `xcopy` instead of `robocopy`, see `xcopy /?` and take a look to the `/m`option.

Whenever a file is changed, the archive flag is set. `xcopy /m ...` copies only files that have the archive flag set and unset it for the sourcefile, so another `xcopy /m ...` would ignore the file, because the archive-bit keeps unset until the file is beeing changed.

(I don't work with robocopy, but I didn't find a similar funktion in it's help - which I find remarkable, because they say robocopy is the better "copy")

**EDIT** to meet the comment:

```
dir /aa "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Backup\testing.txt" >nul 2>&1 && ( goto :fileChanged ) || ( goto :fileUnchanged )
```

`dir /aa` tries to find that file AND it's archive flag beeing set (indicating, the file has been changed). If (the file doesn't exist) or (it exists, but it's archive flag is not set), %errorlevel% will be "1".

Comment: Hi, i have been toying with xcopy also to see if i can tweak it to work as i require, this works well in the aspect it doesn't copy if not modified, but this batch file will run daily, and i will get daily folders created which will be empty, is there a way to prevent folder creation if no update to the file is performed? thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Robocopy can monitor the source and perform a copy when `n` changes are made.  For example:

`robocopy /mon:1 c:\Scripts\ c:\test4\ zzz.cmd /r:5 /w:5`

This will copy the file `zzz.cmd` and instruct RoboCopy to monitor the file and copy again when the source file gets changed, with a 5 retry limit pausing 5 seconds between retry.

Comment: This is a nice feature that i was unaware of thank you, however, this will only monitor the file in the new folder that has been generated, e.g. 0834_04032015, i'm trying to get it to create a new folder with a date on if the file has been modified, if not then don't back it up. perhaps i'm asking too much from a batch file?

Comment: You would just have to wrap the `RoboCopy /Mon:1` command in a batch file using the `errorlevel` check from the `dir /aa` command.  This site is here to help with your coding questions when something doesn't work.